# How to check if a binary file is contained inside another binary from the Linux command line?

Tags: bash, grep, posix, gnu-coreutils

Basically I want a "multiline grep that takes binary strings as patterns".

For example:

```
printf '\x00\x01\n\x02\x03' > big.bin
printf '\x01\n\x02' > small.bin
printf '\x00\n\x02' > small2.bin
```

Then the following should hold:

- `small.bin` is contained in `big.bin`
- `small2.bin` is not contained in `big.bin`

I don't want to have to convert the files to ASCII hex representation with `xxd` as shown e.g. at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217936/equivalent-command-to-grep-binary-files because that feels wasteful.

Ideally, the tool should handle large files that don't fit into memory.

Note that the following attempts don't work.

`grep -f` matches where it shouldn't because it must be splitting newlines:

```
grep -F -f small.bin big.bin
# Correct: Binary file big.bin matches
grep -F -f small2.bin big.bin
# Wrong: Binary file big.bin matches
```

Shell substitution as in `$(cat)` fails because it is [impossible to handle null characters in Bash AFAIK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427262/how-to-read-a-file-into-a-variable-in-shell/22607352#22607352), so the string just gets truncated at the first `0` I believe:

```
grep -F "$(cat small.bin)" big.bin
# Correct: Binary file big.bin matches
grep -F "$(cat small2.bin)" big.bin
# Wrong: Binary file big.bin matches
```

A C question has been asked at: [How can i check if binary file's content is found in other binary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264787/how-can-i-check-if-binary-files-content-is-found-in-other-binary-file) but is it possible with any widely available CLI (hopefully POSIX, or GNU coreutils) tools?

Notably, implementing an non-naive algorithm such as [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm) is not entirely trivial.

I can hack up a working Python one liner as follows, but it won't work for files that don't fit into memory:

```
grepbin() ( python -c 'import sys;sys.exit(not open(sys.argv[1]).read() in open(sys.argv[2]).read())' "$1" "$2" )
grepbin small.bin big.bin && echo 1
grepbin small2.bin big.bin && echo 2
```

I could also find the following two tools on GitHub:

- https://github.com/tmbinc/bgrep in C, installable with (amazing :-)):

  ```
  curl -L 'https://github.com/tmbinc/bgrep/raw/master/bgrep.c' | gcc -O2 -x c -o /usr/local/bin/bgrep -
  ```
- https://github.com/gahag/bgrep in Rust, installable with:

  ```
  cargo install bgrep
  ```

but they don't seem so support taking the pattern from a file, you provide the input as hex ASCII on the command line. I could use:

```
bgrep $(xxd -p small.bin | tr -d '\n') big.bin
```

since it does not matter as much if the small file gets converted with `xxd`, but it's not really nice.

In any case, if I were to implement the feature, I'd likely it to the Rust library above.

bgrep is also mentioned at: [How does bgrep work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31135561/how-does-bgrep-work)

Tested on Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: `rep -f matches where it shouldn't because it must be splitting newlines:` and also it's parsing regex. `grep "$(cat small.bin)"`  fails not only for zero bytes. `grep` expects a regex. Note that your `is it possible with any widely available CLI` is falling into "seeking recommendation of tools" bin.

Comment: @KamilCuk true, added `-F` for non regex. If it closes, I post in other places, the usual procedure.

Comment: `"$(cat file-with-nulls)"` is setting yourself up for failure, since NULs can't be stored in C strings, and all strings in bash are NUL-delimited C strings. For that matter, I'd be very surprised -- nay, astonished -- if `grep` used strings capable of containing NUL literals.

Comment: ...it'd be a more reasonable start to build a version of your Python code that did windowing to search through the file incrementally (obvs., needing some special-case handling around chunk boundaries; but none of that seems particularly tricky so long as a maximum size can be enforced).

Comment: `grep` loads the whole regex pattern into memory. I don't think there's a tool that searches a binary byte stream (not byte buffer...) within a binary file. If the small file fits in memory and the large file is huge, you can write a simple C program that reads the small file, uses its size as a block size, reads blocks from the large file, and tries to find the small file with `memmem()`.

Answer (score 4):

> How to check if a binary file is contained inside another binary from the Linux command line?

The very POSIX portable way would be to use `od` to convert to hex and then check for substring with `grep`, along with some `sed` scripting in between.

The usual normal portable way, would be to use `xxd` instead of `od`:

```
xxd -p small.bin | tr -d '[ \n]' > small.bin2
xxd -p big.bin | tr -d '[ \n]' > big.bin2
grep -F -f small.bin2 big.bin2
```

which works fine tested in `docker` on `alpine` with `busybox`.

But:

> I don't want to have to convert the files to ASCII hex representation with xxd as shown

then you **can't** work with binary files in shell. Pick another language. Shell is specifically created to parse nice looking human readable strings - for anything else, it's utterly unpleasant and for files with zero bytes `xxd` is the first thing you type.

> I can hack up a working Python one liner as follows,

`awk` is also POSIX and available everywhere - I believe someone more skilled in `awk` may come and write the exact 1:1 of your python script, but:

> but it won't work for files that don't fit into memory:

So write a different algorithm, that will not do that.

Overall, when giving the constraint of not using `xxd` (or `od`) to convert a binary file with zero bytes to it's hex representation:

> is it possible with any widely available CLI (hopefully POSIX, or GNU coreutils) tools?

No. Write your own program for that. You may also write it in `perl`, it's sometimes available on machines that don't have `python`.